# How to iterate through a VBA array alphabetically

Tags: vba

I'd like to know if there's a convenient way to sort a returned list alphabetically in VBA when the 'Dir' command is used. For example, if I find files using:

```
strPath = "C:\path\to\pics\"
strFileSpec = "*.png"

' -------------------------- '

strTemp = Dir(strPath & strFileSpec)
```

how can I iterate through them alphabetically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBA doesn't have a built in array sort function. Fortunately, this problem has been solved already by others.

This code was written by Chip Pearson and can be found on [his website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx). It implements the quick sort algorithm.

You can use it like this:

```
QSortInPlace(InputArray)
For i = lbound(InputArray) to ubound(InputArray)
    ' process array items
Next i
```